# Extending existing properties on @types declarations

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to extend the **Request** object of **express** that is available on **express.Request** so that it includes some other data inside the session. I have tried creating my own typings file (**d.ts**) and using the following code:

```
import * as express from 'express';

declare module 'express' {
    export interface Request {
        session: express.Request['session'] & {
            myOwnData: string;
        }
    }
}
```

I am greeted with the following **error**:

```
'session' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.
```

What is the correct way to implement this?

Comment: update the post for imported `express`

Comment: why not create your own Request ? `interface MyRequest extends Request { session: string }`

Comment: Because when I do that, my typescript program is still using the original interface and not the new one. I would have to manually import and use the other name everywhere unless there is another way I am not seeing

Comment: Try using declaration merging to directly extend the static type. Note I didn't find the d.ts declaring `session` (I am on mobile). Second, you could try to type alias before and use the aliased type as the static type for `session`.

Comment: Session is being added by the **express-session** module. Declaration merging is only to add new types not extend them. If I wanted to add something else to the request interface I could do it. What I can't do is update the session that is inside Request. I also tried using a type alias to import Request but the program would still use the original Request interface and not the updated one.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the error you're getting, what version of typescript do you have?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/thunder033/5be457541f115507ad909cd6e4c02ad8 Is this somehow different from your setup? Running fine on TS 2.5.2

Comment: @GregRozmarynowycz I am running on TS 2.6.2. I am amazed on how it works on you...

Comment: Tried your version with webstorms... Is this a joke? http://prntscr.com/hzqg50

Comment: Haha no, its seems to work pretty seemlessly for me: https://imgur.com/gallery/YioQq

Comment: The code in my gist is an abridged version of what I just dropped into an existing (tiny, like 50 lines) express project, EDIT: If I pull out the triple-slash reference, I still get the code assistance...might be because it's named `express.d.ts`???

Comment: @GregRozmarynowycz Even though I get the error, Auto complete does work partially ( it shows my own added properties but not the properties that are available to session by default. ) This is done only on webstorms. On vs code it simply does not auto complete at all. I can also not compile since it displays the same error. I tried naming the file express.d.ts and also adding it into **tsconfig.json**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163082/discussion-between-greg-rozmarynowycz-and-itsundefined).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So looking at the [`express-session`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express-session/index.d.ts) type declaration, it declares a `Session` (and modified `Request` object) under the `Express` namespace. Using this we can create a type declaration (`mySession.dt.s`) to augment the default properties, bypassing the limits of declaration merging:

```
import {Express} from 'express';
import 'express-session';

declare module 'express' {
    export interface Request {
        session: Express.Session & {
            myOwnData: string;
            myOwnData2: number;
            myOwnData3: boolean;
        };
    }
}
```

Note that it seems that the compiler is somewhat flexible about the imports in this file (like it doesn't seem to care if `Express` or `Request` is imported), but being explicit will be most consistent.

We can then import this declaration into our server file:

```
import express = require('express');
import {Express, Request, Response} from 'express';
import './mySession';
import * as session from 'express-session';

const app: Express = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || process.env.NODE_PORT || 3000;

app.use('/endpoint', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
   const a: number = req.session.myOwnData3 + 2; // fails to compile and highlighted by editors
   console.log(req.session.myOwnData); // compiles and provided autocomplete by Webstorm
   // do stuff
   return res.ok();
});

app.use(session(/** do session stuff **/));

log.info(`Start Express Server on ${PORT}`);
app.listen(PORT);
```

As tested, this structure achieves type-safety on the added properties, and intellisense/autocomplete in both VSCode and WebStorm with both the `express-session` and added properties.

Unfortunately, as you noted, this won't be applied globally where type inference is utilized, (only where you explicitly import `Request`). If you want full control over the interface, you could uninstall `@types/express-session` and just copy & modify the d.ts (and import that). Another possibility is to declare a totally new property and implement, but obviously a lot more work.